# How to debug errors as "Unresolved Externals"?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, error-handling, qt-creator

Hope you're doing well.

I'm getting an error in my code[Qt] which shows the message as "Unresolved Externals" in the location of filename.dll. I have no idea how to resolve it. Has anyone ever encountered this kind of error? If so, how have you removed that?

Understanding errors from error messages in Qt are not so easy in Qt, I feel, even when the files having errors can be located easily. Can someone suggest to me an efficient way to remove errors in Qt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: In qt-creator you likely will need to edit your `.pro` file telling your linker what third party libraries your code needs to link to. If this is your own code and you are not usin third party libraries perhaps you forgot to implement a function that you declared in your header. Or perhaps you have a .cpp file but its not listed in your .pro or .pri files so Qt-Creator is ignoring the file. There are other additional options described in the linked duplicate.